# VBA Unlock Cells in a Range if colorindex = 0

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to unlock cells in a given range if they do not have a background color.

```
Sub macunlock()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:C1")
For Each cell In rng1
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then cell.Locked = False
Next cell
End Sub
```

However, the specified cells do not unlock.

Comment: and what happens???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, blank formats are `-4142` and not `0`

Change to this:

```
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then cell.Locked = False
```

Robust way:

```
Sub macunlock()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:C1")
    For Each cell In rng1
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexNone Then
            cell.Locked = False
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```